# Custom authorization attribute not working in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, filter, authorization

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
 {  
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
       return true;// if my current user is authorised
    }
 }
```

Above is my CustomAuthorizeAttribute Class
and

```
[CustomAuthorize] // both [CustomAuthorize] and [CustomAuthorizeAttribute ] I tried 
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{
   //My Code..
}
```

When I'm calling

```
http://localhost:1142/api/Profile
```

It is not firing `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`

More over My FilterConfig class is look like below

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {            
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Please help if I miss something.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Looks like you are using an MVC filter instead of a Web API filter. It can be detected in the sample because it uses `HttpContextBase`. Instead use the filter from the `System.Web.Http.Filters`  namespace.
2. You need to override OnAuthorization **or** OnAuthorizationAsync on the Web API filter.
3. You don't need to register a global filter and decorate your controller with it. Registering it will make it run for all controllers.

Web API filter code:
https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/AuthorizationFilterAttribute.cs

Comment: @ChaoticCoder Looks like the link [has been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23344743/4).

Answer (score 13):

YOur custom attribute should inherit from **System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute**

and it should look like this

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{   
    public override bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Perform your logic here
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try with this.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou .. but I got build error like no suitable method to override (Actually in AuthorizeAttribute there is no such method)  :(

Comment: This attribute comes from the System.Web.Http. If you are using the System.Web.Mvc attribute you should override the AuthorizeCore method instead!

Comment: This is the stuff you actually need. Simply giving a bool if the user is authorized or not.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the other answers that have you inherit from `System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, I put this into my `OnAuthorization` method to make sure the user was logged in:

```
if (!actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
     // or whatever sort you want to do to end the execution of the request
     throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
}
```