# Unable to get custom authorize attribute to work in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created my own Authorized Attribute as such:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(filterContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I then decorated my controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/service")]
[MyCustom]
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
}
```

I set break points in my MyCustomAttribute class however it doesn't appear to be getting called.

How do I get my custom attribute to work?

I also tried registering by filter in the FilterConfig.  That didn't work, plus from what I read that would apply to all methods in my solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339002/custom-authorization-attribute-not-working-in-webapi ?

Comment: Confirmed duplicate.  That was the issue I was using System.Web.MVC instead of System.Web.Http.Filters